# Why might a MacBook not detect an Apple A1152 Mighty Mouse?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, mouse

It seemed that the USB connection was OK.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: We'll need a lot more info to help you. What happens when you connect the mouse? Does it need drivers? What mouse is it?

Comment: @Nathan no drivers required, Apple mighty mouse A1152. Actually, nothing happened when the mouse connected.

Comment: What version of the Mac OS are you running? Have you upgraded it recently? When was the last time that the mouse was working correctly, and what have you changed on your system since that time? Have you installed any new software whatsoever? Have you experienced any crashes? Please provide more details.

Comment: Does one USB port of the MacBook seem more problematic than other USB ports?

Answer (score 1):

With a problem such as this, the first thing you must always try is to connect a *different* USB mouse. If one works, and the other doesn't, then the problem is almost certainly with a defective mouse, and not with the computer. This is a basic troubleshooting step known as "isolating the fault".

In all problems of this sort (not just with mice) you need to test with a second peripheral that you know is working correctly, which we refer to as the "known good" item.

Comment: Additionally: test the mouse on another computer to see if it works there.

Answer (score 0):

Open system profiler and look at the USB connection area. You can refresh to see if it's seen on the system bus. If it is - look in the console app - system.log for more USB related errors.

If it isn't then it's a bad port / cable or mouse.